# problem getting value of a input field in eventListener function

Tags: javascript

```
//get the value from fist name field
var first_name = document.getElementsByName('first_name')[0].value.replace(/\s+$/, '');

//console log the entered first name
signup_submit.addEventListener('click',function(){
   console.log(first_name);
}
```

the result of the above code logs "" in console after entering the first name in first_name field and hitting the signup_submit

but when I declare the var first_name inside the event listener function it is working well. Why does this happen?

Comment: because you get the value when it renders, that does not keep updating...

Comment: @epascarello Thank you so much for clearing my doubt. Now I understand

Answer (score 0):

The value does not keep updating as the user changes the value. The variables value is set in stone once it runs.

So when you moved it inside, it was reading the current value, hence why it worked. That is typically how you would handle reading the value if you just need it in one place.

If you need a global variable for some reason, you want the variable to update. You will need to change the code to run a function when the input's value is changed.

```
var firstNameElem = document.getElementsByName('first_name')[0];
var first_name;
function setName() {
 first_name = firstNameElem.value.replace(/\s+$/, '');
}
setName();
firstNameElem.addEventListener("input", setName);

//console log the entered first name
signup_submit.addEventListener('click', function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(first_name);
}
```

Other option is make a function that retrieves the string

```
var firstNameElem = document.getElementsByName('first_name')[0];
function getName() {
  return firstNameElem.value.replace(/\s+$/, '');
}

//console log the entered first name
signup_submit.addEventListener('click', function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no value to the field on initial rendering you are getting ‘’ as the value. When you enter text, the value changes so you need to to get the value of the input at the time of the click - simply put the query inside the click handler.

```
signup_submit.addEventListener('click',function(){

//get the value from first name field
var first_name = document.getElementsByName('first_name')[0].value.replace(/\s+$/, '');


 //console log the entered first name
   console.log(first_name);
}
```

Comment: OP wanted to know why.... I guess you did not read the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Just because when the page is rendered the first time, query "document.getElementsByName" is triggered with the empty input -> first_name = ""
Then You type in the Input but first_name is still the same cause "document.getElementsByName" is not triggered anymore.

And when you "declare the var first_name inside the event listener function" -> Each time you click -> The new first_name is "declared again" and it get current value in Input

Answer (score 0):

The value of the input field does not change by itself, it's waiting for user input after the page is loaded.

So if you assign the empty input value it to a variable initially, that's the value. The event handler should *reread* the value. You can to that for example using a `keyup` handler

```js
const firstName = document.querySelector("input[name='first_name']")
 .value.trim() || "first_name is empty";

// firstName is empty at this point
console.log(firstName);

// on typing, retrieve and show the value
document.addEventListener("keyup", evt => {
   if (evt.target.name === "first_name") {
    console.clear();
    // reading the *current* value
    const currentValue = evt.target.value;
    console.log( `[${currentValue.trim() || "empty"}]` );
   }
   return true;
});
```

```html
<input name="first_name" placeholder="type your first name">
```